# Laravel - Confusion between routes and middleware and VueRouter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, middleware

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and `Vuejs 2.3` along with `VueRouter`

I have a website that consists in two parts

1. example.com
2. example.com/tools

For the explanation we will determine two kinds of user:

1. Public user whose `user->public_only = true`
2. Stats user whose `user->stats_only = true`
3. Guest user who are not logged in

---

## Here is what I try to achieve

`example.com` should be accessible only by `public user` or `guest user`. That is to say, if a user is already logged as a `stat user`, I want to `logout` the user before reaching the page `/`

`example.com/tools` should be accessible only by `stats user`. That is to say, if a user is already logged as a `public user` or is a `guest user`, I want to redirect the user to the login page before reaching the page `/tools`.

To do so, I created the two middleware `checkUserStats` and `checkUsersPublic`

Everything works pretty well. When I'm a `public user` or a `guest user` who wants to get to `/tools` I'm getting the login page.
When I'm a `stats user` who wants to visit `/` I'm being log out and I'm redirecting to the home page.

---

## Problem

When I'm a `public user` or a `guest user` who wants to get to `/tools` I'm getting the login page. When I fill the 'login' page I'm accessing to the `example.com/tools` which is good.

But I if refresh the page, I'm getting again redirected to the `login` page. I managed to figure out that when refreshing the page, the code go through `HomeController@home` before getting `'StatsController@home'`. So it goes trough `checkUsersPublic` and I'm getting logically logged out since I'm not a `public user`

## Question

How could I do so when I'm here `example.com/tools` and I'm refreshing the page I'm not being redirected first to `/` but to `/tools` directly ?

Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do that would solve this issue ?

---

---

---

#### Routes in Laravel

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');
Route::get('/tools', 'StatsController@home');
```

#### Vue router

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: App },
    { path: '/tools', component: Stats },
];
```

#### HomeController

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('checkUsersPublic');
    }

    public function home()
    {
        return view('app');
    }
}
```

#### StatsController

```
class StatsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('checkUsersStats');
    }

    public function home()
    {
        return view('app');
    }
}
```

#### Middleware checkUsersPublic

```
class checkUsersPublic
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->public_only) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        if(Auth::check()) {Auth::logout();}
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

#### Middleware checkUsersPublic

```
class checkUsersStats
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->stats_only) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if(Auth::check()) {Auth::logout();}
        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by simplifying the problem. It is explained in this topic

[Laravel - Middleware triggered while it should not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939648/laravel-middleware-triggered-while-it-should-not).

Basically instead of doing t he middleware with Laravel, you need to let `vue-router` handles that.