# Laravel - Middleware triggered while it should not?

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-5.4, vue-router

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and `Vuejs 2.3` along with `VueRouter`

I have a website that consists of two parts

1. example.com
2. example.com/tools

## Problem

If I am at `example.com/tools` and if I `reload the page` to the same address `example.com/tools` the middleware `checkUsersPublic` is triggered whereas it is only linked to `/`.

## Edit

If I remove `{ path: '/tools', component: Stats }` from `VueRouter.js` the middleware is not triggered anymore

## Question

- What should I do change so the middleware is not triggered ?

---

#### Routes in Laravel

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home')->middleware('checkUserPublic')
Route::get('/tools', 'StatsController@home')->middleware('checkUserStats')
```

#### Vue router

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: App },
    { path: '/tools', component: Stats },
];
```

#### Middleware checkUsersPublic

```
class checkUsersPublic
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->public_only) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        if(Auth::check()) {Auth::logout();}
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please open your browser's developer tools and Network tab in it. Check 'Preserve log' checkbox and reload `example.com/tools`. Tools will show you what requests are sent to backend. Then update question with this info.

Comment: I added what you proposed. It goes to `localhost` so to `/` but with `undefined` initiator ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the middleware in `Laravel` I did it within `vue-router` in the `beforeEnter` guard